# Getting a "Resource not found when adding [HttpPost] to Edit method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

The error message I get:

> **The resource cannot be found.**
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Member/EditMember

My Actionlink that calls the Edit method looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Rediger", "EditMember", new { item.MemberID })
```

And the view that represents the EditMember page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditMember", "Member", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MemberID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "Navn skal angives", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div
...
}
```

And the controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
    public ActionResult EditMember(Member model)
    {
        Member members = new Member();
        var member = DBContext.Members.Find(model.MemberID);

        if (member == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {                                
            DBContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(member);
    }
```

I have also tried to change the action methods parameter so it looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public ActionResult EditMember(int? id) { ... }
```

But the error remains the same.

**HOWEVER...**

If I remove the `[HttpPost` annotation, then the error dissappears, and it will find the requested URL. But it just won't submit the changes and save them to the database.

That is, if I do:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public ActionResult EditMember(Member model)
```

Then it finds the requested URL, but doesn't save the changes to the database.

What might be my problem?

Comment: Are you saying the error occurs when you click the link (i.e. to your GET method), or when you submit the form to your POST method?)

Comment: The error comes when I click the link

Comment: Clicking a link will perform a GET not a POST operation

Comment: You need both a `[HttpGet]` and a `[HttpPost]` method

Comment: @DavidG Does this mean I need an extra method? So I have one for GET, and one for POST? The examples I've seen abt C# MVC (To edit a record) only have one action, and I tried to do what they do.

Comment: And it would be `[HttpGet] public ActionResult EditMember(int? id) { ... }` and the link needs to be `@Html.ActionLink("Rediger", "EditMember", new { id = item.MemberID })`

Comment: It's pretty common to have two methods, one to display a form and one to accept the `POST` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are not passing the Id in the HttpGet method. This could be as a result of using a ViewModel to display member info.

There is no row in the table with the specified member Id.

**In your controller you should have two actions (HttpGet and HttpPost)**

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult EditMember(int id)
{
    var member = db.member..SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    if (member != null)
    {
        var memberViewModel = new MemberViewModel();
        memberViewModel.MemberID = member.Id;
        memberViewModel.FirstName = member.FirstName;
        memberViewModel.LastName = member.LastName;
        return View(memberViewModel);
    }

    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public ActionResult EditMember(Member model)
{
    Member members = new Member();
    var member = DBContext.Members.Find(model.MemberID);

    if (member == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {                                
        DBContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(member);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that's the issue, since it works fine if I remove the HttpPost attribute. I am trying out the solution some suggested with adding a GET method. But thanks, I'll try your solution if the other attempt doesn't work.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the [HttpPost] for EditMember, inspect the model. Confirm if the Id value actually exist in table

Comment: Would I need to add an extra view as well? Right now I have added one more action method, but this one is just a GET. But how will the program know which one to use?

Comment: It throws an error before it runs the C# code. But if I remove the [HttpPost] attribute, then it works, and the model does indeed have the correct ID

Comment: Please share the error message. I have also updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying that answer before you provided, after Stepen Muecke and DavidG suggested it. But since I do not have the possibility to accept their answers, I will accept yours. And you put a some nice work and time to your answer, which others undoubtedly will benefit from.